# Hover not working when targeting parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with changing divs border color when hovering button. I'v also tried using ID's but something is clearly not right. Even in google developer mode there's no proof of this working.

```
.third-section > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) button:hover .third-section > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1){
    border-color: #c8d400;
}
```

Both paths for button and div itself are correct. Separately they are working just fine. This combination just ain't. Am i missing something ?

//Edit

I have more of this combo in code and none is working with :hover

//Edit2

Adding html

```
<section class="third-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>POZNAJMY SIĘ</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <iframe width="420" height="315"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
                        </iframe>
                        <p>Przeczytaj krótkie case study z mojej pracy.</p>
                        <button>PRZECZYTAJ</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <img class="s-third-icon" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/assets/images/icons/Probki_glosu_icon.svg">
                            <p>Odsłuchaj próbek mojego głosu.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                                <button>SŁUCHAJ PL <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                                <button>SŁUCHAJ EN <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <img class="s-third-icon" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/assets/images/icons/Portfolio_icon.svg">
                        <p>Zajrzyj do mojego CV oraz portfolio</p>
                        <button>POBIERZ</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you also provide the html?

Comment: `button:hover .third-section` — That space is a **descendant** combinator, the section which is a member of that class is an ancestor of the button, not a descendant.

Comment: Ok so jQuery.
Thanks for clarify